# Oracle merge with charset conversion through multiple DBLinks

Tags: oracle, merge, character-encoding, dblink

**Objective:** 
I want to load data from `TABLE_X` located in the `DBLINK1` into `TABLE_Y` located in the `DBLINK2`.

I also need to handle different charsets, so I use the oracle `CONVERT` function and the `TRANSLATE` function to replace accented characters.

The simplified `MERGE` command would look like the following:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_Y@DBLINK2 TABLE_ACTUAL
USING(SELECT ID,
             TRANSLATE(CONVERT(NAME, 'WE8PC850', 'WE8ISO8859P1'), 'Ã', 'A') NAME
        FROM TABLE_X@DBLINK1) TABLE_NEW
   ON (TABLE_ACTUAL.ID = TABLE_NEW.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET NAME = TABLE_NEW.NAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, NAME) VALUES(TABLE_NEW.ID, TABLE_NEW.NAME);
```

This command runs with no issue, but the values in the `NAME` column are not converted nor translated when I look into the `TABLE_Y@DBLINK2`.

When I use a slightly different approach as shown bellow, the `CONVERT` and `TRANSLATE` operations are done successfully.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR CUR_TABLE IS
    SELECT ID,
           TRANSLATE(CONVERT(NAME, 'WE8PC850', 'WE8ISO8859P1'), 'Ã', 'A') NAME
      FROM TABLE_X@DBLINK1;

BEGIN
  FOR REG_TABLE IN CUR_TABLE LOOP  
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TABLE_Y@DBLINK2(ID, NAME)
      VALUES(REG_TABLE.ID, REG_TABLE.NAME);

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
          UPDATE TABLE_Y@DBLINK2
            SET NAME = REG_TABLE.NAME
          WHERE ID = REG_TABLE.ID;
     END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

The problem with the second approach is that it takes way longer to execute compared to the merge command.

**Question:** Is there any plausible explanation as to why `CONVERT` and `TRANSLATE` functions wouldn't work when used with the `MERGE` command?

**Additional info:**

```
CURRENT DB: Oracle 10
DBLINK2 (destination): Oracle 12
DBLINK1 (origin): Unknown version
```

---

**Update:**
As @Kacper suggested, I tried using the `DRIVING_SITE` hint to force oracle to evaluate the expressions on the local database.

The final working solution:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_Y@DBLINK2 TABLE_ACTUAL
USING(SELECT /*+DRIVING_SITE(DUAL)*/ 
             ID,
             TRANSLATE(CONVERT(NAME, 'WE8PC850', 'WE8ISO8859P1'), 'Ã', 'A') NAME
        FROM TABLE_X@DBLINK1, 
             DUAL
        WHERE ID > 0) TABLE_NEW
   ON (TABLE_ACTUAL.ID = TABLE_NEW.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET NAME = TABLE_NEW.NAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ID, NAME) VALUES(TABLE_NEW.ID, TABLE_NEW.NAME);
```

Weirdly enough, it only fully worked after I put a dummy where clause (`ID > 0`) on the source `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand the difference is in approach 2 you pull data from `DBLINK1` to local database, do the conversion on local database and then insert transformed data to `DBLINK2`. Approach 1 will do translation eiter on `DBLINK1` or `DBLINK2` you can try to control it by `DRIVING_SITE` hint.

I'm not sure if it help but I would try `create view db1_v as SELECT ID, TRANSLATE(CONVERT(NAME, 'WE8PC850', 'WE8ISO8859P1'), 'Ã', 'A') NAME FROM TABLE_X@DBLINK1` and then merge using view.

In worst case if that is not helping `create table t1 as SELECT ID, TRANSLATE(CONVERT(NAME, 'WE8PC850', 'WE8ISO8859P1'), 'Ã', 'A') NAME FROM TABLE_X@DBLINK1` and use new table for merge.

Comment: The DRIVING_SITE hint was the key. I updated the question with the final solution. Thanks.